converting email.message.EmailMessage to dictionary in python
I was working with strings like below in python:
'Message-ID: <9803411.1075852365218.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\nDate: Thu, 24 May 2001 15:27:00 -0700 (PDT)\nFrom: john.forney@enron.com\nSubject: Send in your registration card\nMime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\nX-From: John M Forney <John M Forney/HOU/ECT@Enron>\nX-To: \nX-cc: \nX-bcc: \nX-Folder: \\JFORNEY (Non-Privileged)\\Forney, John M.\\To Do\nX-Origin: FORNEY-J\nX-FileName: JFORNEY (Non-Privileged).pst\n\n\tTASK ASSIGNMENT\n\n\nTask Priority:\t\t1\nTask Due On:\t\t\nTask Start Date:\t\n\nFill out and return your registration card or register by phone or fax today!\n\nOnly registered users get:\n-FREE technical support\n-SPECIAL OFFERS on Palm III accessories and add-ons\n-SNEAK PREVIEWS of new product enhancements and software releases\n\nYour registration card also serves as proof of purchase for:\n-Discounts on product upgrades\n-Warranty coverage'

I parse it using email using BytesParser from email.parser module.
output of this function is BytesParser. Now I can access its components like what I did in dictionary. but it is not real dictionary. I want to convert this type to dictionary so I can append it to a dictionary with the columns similar to this datatypes keys.
How to do this? Is there any method to do this conversion for me?
I tried so far this technique:
def extract_fields_from_msg(msg):
    fields = {
        'Message-ID': msg['Message-ID'],
        'Date': msg['Date'],
        'From': msg['From'],
        'Subject': msg['Subject'],
        'Mime-Version': msg['Mime-Version'],
        'Content-Type': msg['Content-Type'],
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': msg['Content-Transfer-Encoding'],
        'X-From': msg['X-From'],
        'X-To': msg['X-To'],
        'X-cc': msg['X-cc'],
        'X-bcc': msg['X-bcc'],
        'X-Folder': msg['X-Folder'],
        'X-Origin': msg['X-Origin'],
        'X-FileName': msg['X-FileName'],
        'Body': msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content() if msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')) else None
    }
    return

but I want to know if is there any mechanism which is easier?! for example I saw this datatype has the method .keys() which returns keys and also value in each field is accessible like accessing values in dictionary using key. If it had a method like .values() it could be so good.

What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

@KlausD. I edited my question and add my attempts.

@KlausD. Also my tried technique is so time consuming. If you could give me some tips to make it faster it would be greatly appreciated.

Like dict(msg.items())?
